# What's the meaning of Event Pooling?

Tags: reactjs

[react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

```
function onClick(event) {
console.log(event); // => nullified object.
console.log(event.type); // => "click"
const eventType = event.type; // => "click"

setTimeout(function() {
console.log(event.type); // => null
console.log(eventType); // => "click"
 }, 0);

// Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
this.setState({clickEvent: event});

// You can still export event properties.
this.setState({eventType: event.type});
}
```

why `event` is already a nullified object,we can still get the value of `event.type`?
doesn't this mean `event = {type:null}`?

```
setTimeout(function() {
console.log(event.type); // => null
console.log(eventType); // => "click"
 }, 0);
```

why `event.type = null` and `eventType = 'click'`?

can you teach me every line of this code? ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClick(event) {
    console.log(event); // => nullified object.
    console.log(event.type); // => "click"
```

We can access all properties of `event` inside the handler.

```
    const eventType = event.type; // => "click"
```

We are copying `event.type` into a local variable. Local variable won't be affected by nullifying.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
```

Everything in the function will be invoked when the handler has already returned, that means, after event nullifying.

```
       console.log(event.type); // => null
       console.log(eventType); // => "click"
   }, 0);
```

So, we cannot access `event.type` because it will be nullified. We will be able to access `eventType` which is a local variable and its contents won't be affected.

```
   // Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
   this.setState({clickEvent: event});
```

`event` is the event that is going to be nullified. Saving its reference to state won't help us.

```
   // You can still export event properties.
   this.setState({eventType: event.type});
}
```

Saving the `event.type` is fine. This is the same as saving `event.type` into a local variable. We are copying the value into our internal state before nullifying.

Comment: It seems like `console.log(e)` is Asyn, but why  isn't `console.log(e.type)`?

Comment: after event pooled `console.log(event.type)` === `console.log(null.type)` ?